# What is the correct MONGO_URL setting for replica sets on Meteor 1.4.1.1

Tags: mongodb, meteor, heroku, mongodb-replica-set

This morning I went to deploy my updated Meteor project onto Heroku.

I was upgrading from `1.1.0.3` to `1.4.1.1`.

Using the [Meteor Buildpack Horse](https://github.com/AdmitHub/meteor-buildpack-horse) everything installed correctly, but the application was erroring out with the error;

> MongoError: seed list contains no mongos proxies, replicaset connections requires the parameter replicaSet to be supplied in the URI or options object, mongodb://server:port/db?replicaSet=name

My `MONGO_URL` was `mongodb://u:p@url1:port,url2:port/db` so I changed it to;

`mongodb://u:p@url1:port,url2:port/db?replicaSet=set-name`

If I made a mistake with the replicaSet param I would get this error;

> MongoError: no primary found in replicaset

Which seems sensible, since the replicaset didn't exist, but when I put the correct value in I get that original error again saying the seed list contains no proxies.

My replica set has a dash in the name, I don't know if that is relevant.

### What I've tried

I've tried using the URL that throws this error in a Mongo client and it allows me to connect to the instance fine, so I know all the details are correct.

I've also tried escaping the replicaSet, so `?replicaSet=set\-name` this gave me the `MongoError: no primary found in replicaset` error.

I have an open ticket with my MongoDB provider, but I suspect this is a Meteor/me issue!

Comment: I don't think you're doing anything wrong which is really strange. I am currently using the following structure in an app I am working on:

    ```mongodb://username:password@url1.com:PORT1,url2.com:PORT2/database?replicaSet=set-000000a0aaaa0000a00000a0```

Comment: Also keep in mind your meteor settings file follows strict JSON requirements (no trailing commas for example).

Comment: @AndrewHill can you elaborate on the strict JSON requirements? Where could I be running foul of that? (my settings.json is empty)

Comment: another suggestion, maybe there's issue with mongo package, in our production we use `mongo@1.1.12`

Comment: Where is your DB hosted? Did you update the `MONGO_OPLOG_URL` variable as well? Have you seen [this issue](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/issues/7450)?

Comment: @MasterAMthat OPLOG was exactly the issue! Thank you so much! My google-fu failed me there.

Can you write up as an answer and I will send the bounty!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Meteor v1.4 uses a new version of the MongoDB driver.

While the `MONGO_URL` environment variable was in the correct form, the error was caused by `MONGO_OPLOG_URL`, which should be modified to include a `replicaSet` argument.

See [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/issues/7450) for more details and the following notes (regarding Compose.io).

From the [oplog driver documentation](https://github.com/meteor/docs/blob/master/long-form/oplog-observe-driver.md#oplogobservedriver-in-production):

> Oplog tailing is automatically enabled in development mode with `meteor run`, and can be enabled in production with the `MONGO_OPLOG_URL` environment variable.
>
> (...)
>
> To use oplog tailing in your production Meteor app, your MongoDB servers must be configured as a [replica set](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/replication/); a single-`mongod` database has no oplog. Your cluster may not use Mongo sharding.

And the [migration guide](https://guide.meteor.com/1.4-migration.html#update-from-mongo-2_4):

> As of 1.4, you must ensure your `MONGO_OPLOG_URL` contains a `replicaSet` argument (see [the changelog](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/blob/devel/History.md#v14) and [the oplog documentation](https://github.com/meteor/docs/blob/master/long-form/oplog-observe-driver.md#oplogobservedriver-in-production)).
>
> > NOTE: Some MongoDB hosting providers may have a deployment setup that doesn't require you to use a `replicaSet` argument. For example, [Compose.io](https://www.compose.io/) has two types of deployments, MongoDB Classic and MongoDB+. The new MongoDB+ offering is a sharded setup and not a true replica set (despite the shard being implemented as a replica set) so it does not require the `replicaSet` parameter and Meteor will throw an error if you add it to your connection strings.

Comment: What if you don't want to use Oplog?

Comment: @Yeats, Simply don't set the `MONGO_OPLOG_URL` environment variable. But if you do, make sure it follows the requirements.